# How do I add a cover image to a MP4 file with ffmpeg?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, mp4, windows-explorer

In Windows Explorer, when in the "Large icons" or "Extra large icons" layout, a MP4 file appears as a thumbnail. By default, the thumbnail image is taken from some frame in the middle of the video.

How do I replace this automatically generated thumbnail with a specific cover image?

What ffmpeg commands will add a cover image to a MP4 video file?

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with ffmpeg [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717175/). Alternatively, you can use [atomicparsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/):

```
atomicparsley video.mp4 --artwork cover.jpg --overWrite
```

Comment: The issue has been closed as fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Now possible, see link on top of  Q.

Answer (score 5):

> *"So which FFMPEG commands can help me to add an cover image to mp4 video file?"*
>
> Fo sure, only do a try with this code:

```bat
ffmpeg -i "input_file.mp4" -i "Input_file.jpg" -map 1 -map 0  -acodec copy -vcodec copy "output_file.mp4"
```