# FFMPEG add 1 image in frame1 of the video (edited)

Tags: ffmpeg

updated post and edited.
1: i first create 5 seconds clip using 55.png.
[55.png click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y0bb.png)
2: i create **intermediate1.ts** using **outputxx.mp4**

3: than i create intermediate2.ts using 55.mp4
4:finally i use the last command
problem is the second video clip does not show but sound plays and i want it to show its original size after first video clip has finished.
original size
https://streamable.com/jpkqps

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 55.png -t 5 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1280x720 -acodec copy -f mpegts -y outputxx.mp4

ffmpeg -i outputxx.mp4 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1280x720 -q:v 1 -acodec copy -f mpegts -y intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i 55.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -s 1920x1080 -q:v 1 -c:a copy -y intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -y output.mp4
```

so main results should be like first clip should play then start the second just like you will add intro then the video

can i modify this to make conversion faster

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -q:v 1 -preset fast -c:a copy -f mpegts -y output1.ts.
```

or what is the fastest way to make 5 seconds clip from 55.png then add a 55.mp4

this is not right probly but it will give you idea.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 55.png  -t 5 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1280x720 -acodec copy -f mpegts i- 55.mp4 -y intermediate1.ts
```

Comment: If you want to add a custom thumbnail, use the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/54717175

Comment: i have 1.mp4 3 seconds long with guy standing in middle,i have 2.mp4 now i wish to join them both with compression and when playing it back it should fit the screen

Comment: "join" is too ambiguous. Do you mean concatenate, picture-in-picture, side-by-side, or something else?

Comment: check post1 updated.