# How to add a Poster Frame to an MP4 video by timecode?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-thumbnails, mp4box, timecodes

The `mvhd` atom or box of the original Quicktime MOV format supports a `poster time` variable for a timecode to use as a poster frame that can be used in preview scenarios as a thumbnail image or cover picture. As far as I can tell, the ISOBMFF-based MP4 format (.m4v) has inherited this feature, but I cannot find a way to set it using [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) or [MP4box](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/releases) or similar cross-platform CLI software. **Edit:** Actually, neither ISOBMFF nor MP4 imports this feature from MOV. Is there any other way to achieve this, e.g. using something like HEIFʼs derived images with a `thmb` (see [Amendment 2](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c071851_ISO_IEC_14496-12_2015_Amd_2_2018.zip)) role?

[image: <code>mvhd</code> box layout]

The original Apple Quicktime (Pro) editor did have a menu option for doing just that. (Apple [Compressor](https://larryjordan.com/articles/change-your-movies-poster-frame/) and [Photos](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7820966) could do it, too).

[image: Quicktime menu]

To be clear, I do *not* want to attach a separate image file, which could possibly be a screenshot grabbed from a movie still, as a separate track to the multimedia container. I know how to do *that*:

- [Stackoverflow #54717175](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717175/how-do-i-add-a-custom-thumbnail-to-a-mp4-file-using-ffmpeg)
- [Superuser #597945](https://superuser.com/questions/597945/set-mp4-thumbnail)

I also know that some people used to copy the designated poster frame from its original position to the very first frame, but many automatically generated previews use a later time index, e.g. from 10 seconds, 30 seconds, 10% or 50% into the video stream.

Comment: M4Vs are Apple's MP4 variant, not standard ISO. ISOBMFF mvhd does not have provision for poster frame. ffmpeg won't write it for MOV either.

Comment: I see that both ISO/IEC 14496-14 (MP4) and ISO/IEC14496-12 (ISOBMFF) are [freely available standards](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/) and have now checked the PDFs myself. The `mvhd` box is described in ISOBMFF 8.2.2 and lacks some of QuickTime's original MOV properties indeed, including `poster time`. MP4 does not extend (nor even mention) this box. I guess @Gyan therefore answers my original question, because I phrased it in a too narrow way.