# ffmpeg_python library to add a custom thumbnail to a .mp4 file using ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

based on this post

[How do I add a custom thumbnail to a .mp4 file using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717175/how-do-i-add-a-custom-thumbnail-to-a-mp4-file-using-ffmpeg)

**Using ffmpeg 4.0, released Apr 20 2018 or newer,**

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic out.mp4

**As in version 4.2.2...See Section 5.4 in FFmpeg documentation**

To add an embedded cover/thumbnail:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i IMAGE -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic out.mp4
```

how can i do that using ffmpeg_python library
https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if the OP might not need a solution anymore, I came here to find it.

I found an example in the [issues of the ffmpeg_python GitHub repository](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/380#issuecomment-657627892):

```
import ffmpeg

video = ffmpeg.input('in.mp4')
cover = ffmpeg.input('cover.png')
(
    ffmpeg
    .output(video, cover, 'out.mp4', c='copy', **{'c:v:1': 'png'}, **{'disposition:v:1': 'attached_pic'})
    .global_args('-map', '0')
    .global_args('-map', '1')
    .global_args('-loglevel', 'error')
    .run()
)
```