# Use ffmpeg to add a thumbnail to an mp4 with chapters

Tags: ffmpeg

The [awesome trick for adding a thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717175/how-do-i-add-a-custom-thumbnail-to-a-mp4-file-using-ffmpeg) to a simple mp4 video with ffmpeg works perfectly, until I took an mp4 with chapters in it. The thumbnail is added, but the output file can't be played on many devices. This command didn't work as required:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic out.mp4
```

What can be wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: On which app does it fail to play in? I've tested your command and it plays fine in vlc

Comment: Quick Look in macOS and on my TV (doesn't recognize the video format). VLC and IINA do play it, of course.

Comment: And the original video with chapters work on those devices? (I had an issue with pixel format when I tried the test case on FireFox but that was because my input video was encoded in yuv444 not yuv420p)